# F# CPS evaluation order

Tags: functional-programming, f#, continuations, cps

I'm trying to understand the order of evaluation when using Continuation-passing style in F#.
Take this function for example.

```
let rec CPSfunc n k c =
    if k = 0 then c 1
    else if k > 0 then CPSfunc n (k-1) (fun res -> c(2*res+k))
```

When running it with the arguments `CPSfunc 4 3 id` it evaluates to `19`, but when I try to evaluate it by hand, I get different results, based on evaluating forward or backwards first.

```
CPSfunc 4 3 (fun res -> res)
CPSfunc 4 2 (fun res -> fun 2*res+3 -> res)
CPSfunc 4 1 (fun res -> fun 2*res+2 -> fun 2*res+3 -> res)
// Evaluating backwards
fun res -> fun 2*res+2 -> fun 2*res+3 -> 1
fun res -> fun 2*res+2 -> 2*1+3
fun res -> 2*5+2
// Evaluating forward
fun 1 -> fun 2*res+2 -> fun 2*res+3 -> res
fun 2*1+2 -> fun 2*res+3 -> res
fun 2*4+3 -> res
4
```

How do I properly calculate the correct output?

Comment: As given, F# infers the type of `CPSfunc` to `'a -> int -> (int -> unit) -> unit`, which then means that `CPSfunc 4 3 id` doesn't type-check. Did you leave out an `else` branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see that 19 is the correct result, I think it's easiest to start with `k = 0` and increment. Each result is simply twice the previous result, plus `k`. (Note that `n` is not used.) So we have:

```
k = 0 ->     1     =  1
k = 1 -> 2 * 1 + 1 =  3
k = 2 -> 2 * 3 + 2 =  8
k = 3 -> 2 * 8 + 3 = 19
```

Converting that simple logic into continuations gets complicated, though. Here's what the expansion looks like in F# for `CPSfunc 4 3 id`:

```ml
// unexpanded initial call
let c3 = (fun res -> res)
CPSfunc 4 3 c3

// expanded once, k = 3
let c2 = (fun res -> c3 (2 * res + 3))
CPSfunc 4 2 c2

// expanded again, k = 2
let c1 = (fun res -> c2 (2 * res + 2))
CPSfunc 4 1 c1

// expanded again, k = 1
let c0 = (fun res -> c1 (2 * res + 1))
CPSfunc 4 0 c0

// full expansion, k = 0
c0 1
```

P.S. To make `c` have the desired `int -> int` signature, you need to define `CPSfunc` slightly differently, so that's what I assume you've actually done:

```ml
let rec CPSfunc n k c =
    if k = 0 then c 1
    elif k > 0 then CPSfunc n (k-1) (fun res -> c(2*res+k))
    else failwith "k < 0"
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! And you're right, I forgot to include the failwith statement in the post

Answer (score 2):

```
CPSfunc 4 3 id
CPSfunc 4 2 (fun res -> id(2*res+k))
CPSfunc 4 2 (fun res -> 2*res+3)
CPSfunc 4 1 (fun res -> (fun res -> 2*res+2)(2*res + k))
CPSfunc 4 1 (fun res -> (2*(2*res + 2)+3))
CPSfunc 4 0 (fun res -> (fun res -> (2*(2*res + 2)+3))(2*res + k))
CPSfunc 4 0 (fun res -> 2*(2*(2*res+1) + 2)+3))
(fun res -> 2*(2*(2*res+1) + 2)+3)(1)
2*(2*(2*1+1)+2)+3
19
```

actually ive taken some liberties by evaluating some functions in the above before they would actually be evaluated, but it doesnt really matter